# virtualdub/ffshowtry and audio codecs that should exist

Tags: video, audio, conversion, codec, virtualdub

While trying to convert a video i notice virtualdub cant find my codec (no sound in output file). Even while setting use source audio it cannot find the audio. VLC can play the sound so how can i get virtualdub to use it? I dont see NELL (audio codec) anywhere in ffdshow. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GSpot](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/GSpot.htm) to identify the codec used in your video and then search for it on [free-codecs.com](http://www.free-codecs.com/).

On the other hand, you may just install a codec pack. A very complete one that contains almost every imaginable codec is [K-Lite Mega Codec Pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_Mega_codec_pack.htm).